# VS Code will always highlight matches of word when cursor is on top of that word

Tags: visual-studio-code

My VS Code editor will highlight all matches of a word when I just have the cursor on top of that word.

How do I turn this off? Is this a bug?

[image: screenshot of issue]

Comment: Now, I realise why suddenly this annoyed me so much. The way this displays differs drastically based on what your theme is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just set

```
  "editor.occurrencesHighlight": none
```

in your settings if you don't want those.  Selecting the word will still highlight all occurrences but not just a cursor within the word.

Comment: Thanks, weird that this isn't default behaviour, it is very annoying.

Comment: This feature really should be disabled by default. It’s been driving me crazy!

Comment: Neither `none` nor `"none"` was allowed, but `"off"` did the trick for me!

Answer (score 0):

To assist those fairly new to VS Code's settings.json, I wanted to add a comment to Mark's answer. I lack the rep to do this, so I will add it here.

Even though this issue and answer deals with a highlighting color,  `"editor.occurrencesHighlight": false`, should not be nested in `workbench.colorCustomizations: {}`. It needs sit on the main level as that.

It would look something like this:

```
"editor.occurrencesHighlight": false
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {}
```