# Visual Studio Code adds extra highlighting that makes it hard to tell which text is selected

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm new to Visual Studio Code, having previously used Atom for many years. In the screenshot below, I've only selected the text `Button`, but the editor has added a background color behind the entire `./Button` string. This makes it incredibly difficult to tell which text is actually selected.

[image: Screenshot of a text editor with ambiguously highlighted/selected text]

**How do I stop the editor from adding this extra highlighting to text that isn't selected?** It happens in many other contexts (not just strings) and in other types of files as well (not just JSX, which is what this is).

So far I've:

- Done a bunch of googling and came up empty
- Hunted through and toggled on/off all of the settings I could think of, including anything related to "selection" and "highlighting"
- Tried different themes
- Looked through the VSCode editor syntax highlighting theme documentation to see if there's any kinds of overrides that sound right
- Turned off everything I could find in the settings related to "code actions" thinking it might be something related to that

I'm not even sure what the right term to be searching for is.

Comment: To focus your investigation, you first need to determine things like Language Mode, extensions and theme. In other words, highlighting visuals are determined by the type of file, the extension used to parse that language and the colour theme. Fiddling with global settings is probably not going to work.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález It's happening with multiple languages and file types across multiple themes

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/51425079/836330 but use `"none"` instead of false.

Comment: @Mark You're a lifesaver, thanks! `"none"` wasn't allowed but `"off"` was and it did the job perfectly.